# How to run multiple inputs in Python?

Tags: python

I have an extensive Python script, that runs one input each time.

```
input('Write the file name:')
...
```

And because I have a lot going on in my script (and don't want to change the operations in it), I wanted to know if (and how) there is a way to give my script multiple inputs.

So that I give the script a list of inputs and it runs `input1`, when this one ends, runs the `input2`, etc...

Is there a way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Why can't you just do `fname = input("filename")` and then `fname2 = input("filename2")`?

Comment: Yes I can, but what I wanted to know is, if it's possible to use something more automatic.
For example, have a list = ['filename1', 'filename2'], and put this in an input

Comment: you could have a list like you mentioned and then loop over that list getting input

Comment: @TheBigKahuna Did what you said and it does what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make it more automatic you can use the following code:

x, y, z = input("input1: "), input("input2: "), input("imput3: ")

Answer (score 0):

Your situation can be solve using `sys.argv`.

To run your code, you would type in `python script.py input1 input2 input3`.

Then, use `sys.argv` as follows:

```py
import sys
sys.argv  #returns ["script.py", "input1", "input2", "input3"]
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.
In that way I will have to write by hand all my inputs. I have a long list with inputs, list= `[01-01-2020, 02-01-2020, ...]`
Is there a way in which I can give the scritpt the list and the script will run the inputs one by one?

Comment: can  you help me with type of input you are expecting and are they in any sequence ?